# python programming to take input(3),first two are for range and third for divisibility between range

Tags: python-3.x

```
I WANT TO TAKE 3 INPUTS IN A SAME LINE ,HELP ME WITH INPUT

I HAVE TRIED TAKING 3 VARIABLES AND DIVING THEM BY SPLIT

a,b,c=int(input().split())
count=1
for i in range(a,b+1):
    if(i%c==0):
        count+=1
print(count)

a,b,c=int(input().split())
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

please give me solution, i want to take fist two numbers AS range and didvide it with 3rd number

Comment: All upper-case is the same as shouting, and shouting is considered rude.

Comment: Also please take some time to  read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: This is awful code. Pick up a python textbook or just watch a youtube video, because it looks like you're writing a c program with no spaces

Comment: You are calling `int` on the output of `split()`. The output of `split()` is a list — so `int()` doesn't know what to do. Try mapping `int()` over the list: `a,b,c = map(int, input().split())` This will call `int()` on each value, which should work so long as the values are what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

`split()` returns a list. `int()` can't do anything with a list. Convert the output of split using a list comprehension:

```
ints = [int(x) for x in input.split()]
```